# Skip Unit Tests -Arcanist

Tags: rspec, arcanist

We (the royal we) have a number of unit tests (several thousand). Some are still dependent on external services because when they were written, the service dependencies were not stubbed out. VCR was used as a way to triage this.

I am spending time cleaning up these old tests (consider it a Zen exercise) and I have a handful of working branches (each branch essentially constitutes the test suite for a specific component[model/controller/etc.. ]. However I want to be able to disable the unit tests for the vast number (~100) test files which are still dependent on the external services

Answer (score 6):

I was able to achieve this by adding `--nounit` as a command line arg